# Load Partial View With Change the URL

Tags: jquery, .net-core

How can i when click the button , the page will load the partial view and url from `'/user/account/payment'` to `'/user/account/profile'` without refresh the web page .

For me load the partial view will only using the jquery 
`$('class').load('partial page')` , but it will not change the URL .

Example website like the https://shopee.com.my/ account page .

Comment: It is not clear to me what your question is. Are you saying that `load` changes your URL or that you want it to?

Comment: Hi @PeterSmith , I just wanna to load the partial view and change the URL without refresh the page .

Comment: Hi @freedomn-m,
I have following this solution . But when i refresh the page will direct to the url .How can I handle the refresh problem ? Due the page is partial view ..

Comment: About the ```onbeforeunload()``` only work on close the window .

Comment: You want to change the URL, but not have it change to that url when you refresh?  What exactly is the purpose here?  The reason you change the url is so that you can directly back to the page the url presents, not some other random page.  It is possible to use url-redirects on the server, but there seems something fundamentally wrong with what it appears you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this Method**

```
$.ajax({
//some jquery ajax call properties
success: function(){
    location.hash = 'your_value';
}
})
```

Comment: Why will this help? An explanation would be good.

Comment: This will help because the page is not refreshed !

Comment: Changing the **hash** will not change the **url** from '/user/account/payment' to '/user/account/profile'`